# document.addEventListener не работает с загруженным svg

Tags: javascript, css, svg, addeventlistener

Я пытаюсь создать проект, в котором пользователь может щелкнуть изображение, а затем загружается интерактивный .svg (внутри тега object). Для этого мне нужно отслеживать движение мыши по всему экрану (а не только .svg) после того, как произошла загрузка.

Однако ни `document.addEventListener`, ни `window.addEventListener` не работают с `*.svg`. Они просто работают за его пределами. Есть ли способ исправить это без необходимости комбинировать `document.addEventListener` и конкретный interactiveSVG.addEventListener`?

Вот мой код (отредактированный):

```
let firstImage = document.querySelector('#my-first-img');
let objectSVG = document.querySelector('#svg-obj');
let interactiveSVG;

firstImage.addEventListener('click', e => {
        objectSVG.data = `mySVG.svg`;
        objectSVG.addEventListener('load', e => {
            interactiveSVG = objectSVG.getSVGDocument();
            document.addEventListener('mousemove', e => {
                console.log(e.clientX);
            });
        });
});
```

<sub>Свободный перевод вопроса [document.addEventListener not working on loaded svg](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71447166/7394871) от участника  [@Fede](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10153623/fede).</sub>

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/71447166/7394871

Comment: Обратите внимание на данный вопрос-ответ. Здесь применяется, на мой взгляд **интересная техника работы внутри тега `<object>`** Что всегда вызывало множество вопросов в связи со специфичностью, ограничениями в работе с внешними файлами SVG, загруженными в HTML с помощью object

Answer (score 2):

Насколько я знаю, SVG внутри `<object>` несколько вас ограничивает. Существуют обширные функции для событий `pointer-events` CSS, которые могут применяться к элементам SVG, которые, к сожалению, не может предоставить `<object>`. Но если вы назначите `pointer-events: none` для SVG, это будет проигнорировано, поэтому события указателя будут срабатывать непосредственно над SVG, но `event.target` будет ближайшим предком DOM-элемента SVG.

Для SVG в `<object>` вам нужен фактический тег `<style>` внутри `<object>` и добавить `pointer-events: none`

```
<object class="map" data="path/to/image.svg" type="image/svg+xml">
  <style>
    .map {
      pointer-events: none;
    }
  </style>
</object>
```

В приведенном ниже примере показано нормальное поведение указателя при наведении или нажатии на SVG. Имейте в виду, что с `pointer-events: none`, на самом деле все взаимодействия происходят в DOM.

***Применение***

Наведите указатель мыши на всю страницу и обратите внимание на координаты `X,Y`, отображаемые в левом углу. SVG обведен красной пунктирной линией, обратите внимание, что события `mousemove` срабатывают, когда курсор находится над SVG.

Щелкните снаружи и внутри SVG. При каждом щелчке будет установлен значок флага (наведите указатель мыши на флаг, и появится всплывающая подсказка с его координатами `X,Y`). Это возможно, потому что каждый флаг имеет позицию: абсолютная, а тело — позиция: относительная.

***Примечание:***

координаты флагов и кодов, отображаемых в углу, не точны, поскольку флаги находятся на смещении измерений `.getBoundingClientRect()` и `clientX/Y`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

*Для установки маркеров на карте, кликнете по месту*

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title></title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <style>
    html {
      font: 1.5ch/1 Consolas;
    }
    
    html,
    body {
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
    }
    
    body {
      position: relative;
    }
    
    fieldset {
      width: max-content;
      padding: 0;
    }
    
    mark {
      position: absolute;
      background: transparent;
    }
    
    mark:after {
      content: '\1f6a9';
      font-size: 1.25rem;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <fieldset>
    <legend><output class="view"></output></legend>
    <object class="map" data="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/41/Simple_world_map.svg" type="image/svg+xml">
          <style>
            .map {
              transform: scale(0.75);
              outline: 1px dashed red;
              pointer-events: none;
            }
          </style>
        </object>
  </fieldset>
  <script>
    document.onmousemove = trackPoint;
    document.onclick = markPoint;

    function trackPoint(e) {
      const view = document.querySelector('.view');
      view.value = `X: ${e.clientX.toString().padStart(3, '0')} : Y: ${e.clientY.toString().padStart(3, '0')}`;
    }

    function markPoint(e) {
      const mark = document.createElement('mark');
      document.body.appendChild(mark);
      getCoords.call(mark, e);
    }

    function getCoords(e) {
      const clk = e.target;
      const rect = clk.getBoundingClientRect();
      const oX = Math.floor(e.clientX - rect.left);
      const oY = Math.floor(e.clientY - rect.top);
      this.style.left = oX + 'px';
      this.style.top = oY + 'px';
      this.title = `[${oX}, ${oY}]`;
    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

<sub>Свободный перевод  [ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71448597/7394871) от участника  [@zer00ne](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2813224/zer00ne).</sub>